MS Word Issue with saving documents to .PDF - not working, due to "insufficient memory"
I’m experiencing an odd issue with Microsoft Word (Office for Small Business 365) on two different computers running Windows 11 Pro. The problem occurs when I use the Save As... function to save a document as a PDF.
System Details:
Computer 1: Intel i9, 16GB RAM
Computer 2: AMD Ryzen, 32GB RAM
Performance shouldn't be an issue on either machine.
Problem Description:
On the first attempt, saving as PDF fails approximately 50% of the time. However, when I click away the error messages and try again, it always works on the second attempt. This behavior is consistent across both computers.
I’ve seen other users report similar issues, such as in these threads:
https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftWord/comments/1dcjwtb/help_saving_documents_to_pdf_not_working_due_to/?rdt=33757
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2016-word-has-insufficient-memory-and-wants/12a933ea-bb48-45d1-86ed-16bb6fd7c32c
Unfortunately, none of the suggested solutions in these threads resolved the issue for me.
Steps Already Tried:
-Updating Microsoft Office to the latest version
-Repairing Office installation
-Saving to different file locations and paths
-Ensuring sufficient permissions and clearing temp files
Does anyone have insight into why this might happen, or suggestions for resolving it? The fact that it works every second time is baffling and suggests some kind of caching or temporary file issue, but I can’t pinpoint the root cause.

We've seen this in our environment when we use the Adobe Save as Adobe PDF, but the Microsoft Save As... and selecting PDF from the pulldown has always worked.

PDF writing is a fine balance of stretched resources. Since long gone are the days they were saved a pure plain text and you knew you had exceeded all the available disk space when disks were 360 KB if empty. Modern problems, usually stem from using virtual drives or dynamic ones where the available size is not instantly known or is interjected by a defender looking for exploits or indexing the bionic hash or contents. THus like  Bruce of Scots you have to try try again sir.
